# Product of nice proper forcing notions

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

**Question** Are there forcing notions $P$ and $Q$ such that $P$ is proper and $\aleph_2$-cc, $Q$ is proper and satisfies the $\aleph_2$-pic (pic=properness isomorphism condition) such that $P \times Q$ is not proper?

**Remark**. I am looking for examples in $ZFC$ (or $ZFC+GCH$).

Comment: What's the definition of pic?

Comment: If $T$ is Suslin, and $P$ is the forcing to specialise it, while $Q=T$, this should work. No?

Comment: I am looking for ZFC examples.

Comment: Are there even known $ZFC(+GCH)$ examples of proper $\aleph_2$-preserving forcings $P, Q$ so that $P\times Q$ is not proper?

Comment: @AndreasLietz I don't know, I asked this special question, as it arose in one of my projects!